# self.write в Tornado не пишет кириллицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

Ниже код на странице выведет кириллицу "Иванов" в неверной кодировке. Данные необходимо писать в виде словаря/json массива.

```
class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data = [{'id':1, 'Name':'Иванов', 'Name2':'Ivanov'}
        for i in data:
            self.write(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен json, [пишите json](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/escape.html#tornado.escape.json_encode):

```
self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(data))
```

Это автоматически о кириллице позаботится (json произвольный Unicode позволяет передавать).